# How to give external jar dependency in Jboss Server?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

Hai i am developing a web application my project need to refer lib(jar) file from server, So I do not want to keep my jar file in project i need to refer the path of the jar files available in server by this i can reduce my .war file size. How can i make this reference in Jboss Server.

Answer (score 2):

the first step you have to add your lib in jboss server like a module, have a look at :
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7
Next if you use Maven for dependencies, add provided to your lib dependency, in that way while packaging the .war maven will keep the jar in your lib and it will be provided by the server.

this can also be helpful : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Add_an_Explicit_Module_Dependency_to_a_Deployment1.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [class loading](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7) documentation. That should give you the information you need.

Comment: I am unable to understand the document can u pls refer any sample project